# Javascript acting funny in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I have a website where I want people to be able to type something in a text box and get sent to that directory based on what they entered.

Say customer numbers, so we have customer # 155. His invoices are in folder `/invoices/155` directory. I want him to be able to type in his customer # and be directed with a button click to his directory with all his invoices.

Now I have coded the below code but it only works when I click on the button with the mouse. In Internet Explorer When I press enter it gives me a bunch of gook in the address bar and doesn't do anything. It looks like this in the address bar:

`file:///C:/Users/My%20Name/Desktop/test.html?dir=%2Finvoices%2F&userinput=155`

Instead of loading the folder `/invoices/155/`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<form name="goto" action="">
<input name="dir" type="hidden" value="/invoices/">
<input name="userinput" type="text"> <input type="button" value="try me" onclick="window.location=this.form.dir.value+userinput.value">

</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code and what can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In some browsers the form will be posted when you press enter, eventhough there is no submit button. Use a submit button, and catch the submit, then you handle all cases:

```
<form name="goto" action="" onsubmit="window.location=this.dir.value+this.userinput.value;return false;">
<input name="dir" type="hidden" value="/invoices/">
<input name="userinput" type="text"> <input type="submit" value="try me">
</form>
```

Comment: Guffa, I changed the code to your suggestion, and now nothing works at all. Neither the mouse clicking the button or the enter press. Both shoot this string to the address bar "http://www.mydomain.com/test.html?dir=%2Finvoices%2F&userinput=170". When the user types in 170 in the input box it should be sending them to "http://www.mydomain.com/invoices/170/" Please suggest how to make this work.

Comment: @MatthewLenfest: Sorry for the bug, in the submit event it should be just `this` instead of `this.form` to access the fields. See the corretion above.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, if you use file protocol. Especially in IE. You need a real web server.

And to let a customer type in his on id is **extremely**  insecure. Anyone could type in any id. Use a login.

It is **really***** important to sanitize **every** user input to prevent abuse.

It is a long way to go.

Comment: There is an .htaccess file for each customers directory with a MD5 hash'd password. This is just to get them to their directory of invoices so they dont have to remember the address.

Comment: yunzen this file is uploaded to an apache2 server fyi.

Comment: Then you have to add the http address of that server to the location.href

Comment: That doesn't matter. The file is in the / directory. So specifying the entire address is the same as the directory down /invoices/ location. But just for shits and giggles I changed it and got the exact same results as the original file.

Comment: You should perhaps not have your starter file on the local file system but already on the websserver. IE might not submit a form as you desire else.

Comment: <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="goto" action="" onsubmit="window.location="http://www.mydomain.com/invoices/"+userinput.value+"/"; return false;">
            <input name="dir" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="userinput" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="try me" >

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

This does the same thing as all the rest of the code. I am not sure what is going on here. But it is not working.

Comment: Ok summary. Use this file on the webserver, not on the local file system. Use a onsubmit handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for `onsubmit` on `<form>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script>
        function handleFormSubmit(form)
        {
            window.location = form.dir.value + form.userinput.value;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return handleFormSubmit(this)">
            <input name="dir" type="hidden" value="/invoices/">
            <input name="userinput" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="try me" >    
    </form>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​
```

BTW:
Inlining javascript is not so good. Use script tag or external .js-file.

**Edit:**
Oops! OK, the error was that I wrote `this.form.dir` but it needed to be `this.dir` because `this` already referred to the form, now that the javascript handler was on the `form` tag (`onsubmit="<handler-code>"`). That works - http://jsfiddle.net/Q875a/

**Edit 2:**
**Inlining javascript** means that you write javascript code in your html tags (`form`, `input`,...) **in** the `onXXX` **attributes** - it's **not readable**. Having your script in a `script` tag within a handler-function (i.e. `handleFormSubmit`) makes it much more readable especially if your site gets more and more script in it - see current script and `onsubmit`-attribute.

Finally, if you want to to take a step further to **crossbrowser, powerful javascript development** you should take a look at [**jQuery**](http://www.jquery.com/) - it's imho the door to really **professional and exiting javascript programming**!

JSFiddle to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/yNTK5/

jQuery-links concerning the topic:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Warappa thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out. Also what is inlining javascript? What is a script tag? I am new to programming javascript.

Comment: I tried your suggestion warappa and the same thing occured. Nothing works now. :-(